# ¿Cómo puedo subir un documento a GitHub desde terminal?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Hola apenas me estoy adentrando a utilizar Git y me estoy guiando por un video en Youtube pero tengo un problema al momento se subir mi documento al repositorio. Utilizo SSH y el error mostrado es:

```
To github.com:usuario/repos.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:usuario/repos.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Hasta ahora he introducido los siguientes comandos:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Comentario"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:usuario/repos.git
git push -u origin main
```

He intentado de otras formas pero obtengo errores como:

```
 1. fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
 2. Couldn't find remote ref master
```

Cualquier comentario es bienvenido, agradezco su tiempo :)

Comment: Cuando creaste el repositorio en Github, marcaste la opción de "Crear un README" (o la de crear un .gitignore, el efecto sería el mismo). Eso causa que el repositorio en github tenga ya un primer commit con el fichero. Por otro lado en tu máquina local también creaste algún fichero y un primer commit. Resulta que tenemos "dos primeros commits", uno en remoto y otro en local. Y eso no puede ser. Al no haber ningún commit en común, las historias de los dos repositorios están "desconectadas" (_unrelated_) de ahí el error.

Comment: Ya te han explicado cómo solucionarlo, pero en lo sucesivo **evita crear** ficheros a través de la interfaz de Github y asegúrate de que el repositorio vacío que creas allí está realmente vacío.

Comment: Hola! Si de hecho ese fue mi error con el README como dice, evitare crear archivos desde interfaz, ahora ya entiendo mejor esta parte. Le agradezco su aportación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya bien lo dice el error que se te genera al hacer `push` a tu repositorio remoto. Tienes cambios o archivos que no están en tu repositorio local

```
Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref
```

Para tener tu repositorio local con los últimos cambios que existen en tu repositorio remoto haz uso del comando `git pull origin main`. Si no tienes "conflictos que resolver" podrás hacer uso del comando `git push -u origin main`

Es probable que al momento de crear el repositorios hayas dejado marcada la opción "Agregar README" (o similar) y sea ese el cambio que no tienes en tus archivos locales.

### Actualización

Como comentas, tienes un problema al momento de ejecutar el comando `git pull origin main` pero me arroja un error "`fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`". Haz uso del comando `git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories` para realizar el forzado en el Merge de tu rama local con la remota. Ese error se genera debido a que no coinciden los commits remotos con los locales.

Comment: De hecho si es como dices, el archivo README, ese no lo tengo en el repositorio local. Ya intente traerlo con el "git pull origin main" pero me arroja un error "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories".

Comment: Comprendo, utiliza el siguiente comando `git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories`

Comment: Funciono! Ingrese el comando y me abrio como un editor de texto dentro de la terminal para agregar el commit, algo raro, pero que funciono, ahora ya pude subir mi documento al repositorio. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!

Comment: Excelente! Asegúrate de marcar mi respuesta como aceptada. Adicional, agregue la actualización con el comando que te funciono.